# What means three dots (...) in typescript besides its meaning as spread operator and rest operator?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, flowtype

I read Reactjs source code and encountered with syntaxes that I can't to understand.

```
//chunk - 1
type Thenable<T> = {
  then(resolve: (T) => mixed, reject: (mixed) => mixed): mixed,
  ...
};

//chunk - 2
type Resource<I, V> = {
  read(I): V,
  preload(I): void,
  ...
};
```

But in previous commit it was like so:

```
//chunk - 3
type Thenable<T> = {
  then(resolve: (T) => mixed, reject: (mixed) => mixed): mixed,
};

//chunk - 4
type Resource<I, V> = {
  read(I): V,
  preload(I): void,
};
```

So absolutely the same but without (...)

The question is what means the three dots in the first two first chunks above (1) and (2)? (Not for what this code is needed and what it does).

What was the intention of the author for adding its?

I know what it means when I use something like this:

```
let a = [1,2,3]
let b = [4,5,6]
let c = [...a, ...b]
```

or

```
function some(a, ...b){
  //something happens here
}
```

In the context it just spread operator and Rest Operator.

Comment: Is this a flow syntax?

Comment: @adiga probably. [It's not valid TS](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAtglgDwgEygXigOwK4wEYQBOUAPlAM7CFyYDmA3FAPRMBW2lUAxoRAIbBofKKEhQAZgHticYACg5LLgAtsmANZQAtFACMc0dAAqyiJj54ANhAA8RgHzooAbzlQRpzAApe5SZYA3CAAuKC8jAEp0R3gkZAAaKF5WCC5gUK9YlCi0GMRs0KyEtygAOnK5AF96IA). It [does seem like valid Flow](https://flow.org/try/#0PTDGAsFcDsGsAIC08CMAoALgTwA4FN4AVcPaAQwCMAbPAHkID54BeeAbzXngxOgAoATngDOAeyoA3PAC54fQgEoWTALYBLAB54AJgBp4QgFZ5QGWX3VbtS5qs06Fsyzt2d4AOk9oAvgG4gA)

Comment: @VLAZ just searched the React code base and [found OP's code](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/9198a5cec0936a21a5ba194a22fcbac03eba5d1d/packages/react-cache/src/ReactCacheOld.js). It's a flow type